# Why does #1 program shows run time error whereas #2 runs correctly?

Tags: string

```
string str="";
for(int j=0;j<str.size()-1;++j)
{
        char t=str[j];
        cout<<"here";
}

string str="";
int s=str.size();
--s;
for(int j=0;j<s;++j)
{
        char t=str[j];
        cout<<"here";
}
```

1. Why does #1 "for loop" not terminate as #2? What is the difference   between these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str.size returns an unsigned number.  There should be a warning, but 0 - 1 as an unsigned number is going to instead be the largest number.  This causes your first loop to run forever (again, there should be warning about comparing signed an unsigned), or more likely, crash because you're accessing stuff outsides the bounds of string.

In your second example, you're converting the unsigned zero to a signed zero (int is signed), and then decrementing it, so it behaves the way you would expect.

In general, compiling your code with warnings turned on (I got two warnings for your first example, the unsigned vs signed and also a less important t is unused) is strongly encouraged.